# Django function, obtain result for show in view

Tags: python, django, function, django-models, orm

I have a function in a django model, this function is for calculating the two fields, but how I can obtain the function result,for  show this in a django view

```
class Player(models.Model): 
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team) 
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    gp = models.IntegerField(max_length=2) #games played 
    mp = models.IntegerField(max_length=4) #minutes played 
    def mpg(self): #minutes per game 
            return self.mp/self.gp 
    def __unicode__(self): 
            return self.first_name+' '+self.last_name
```

When I run "python manage.py shell" and try to pull up a player's 
"mpg", I get:

```
>>> p = Player.objects.get(last_name='Durant') 
>>> p 
<Player: Kevin Durant> 
>>> p.mp 
1027 
>>> p.gp 
27 
>>> p.mpg 
<bound method Player.mpg of <Player: Kevin Durant>>
```

Answer (score 0):

mpg is a method, and like all methods in Python, you need to actually call it to get its result:

```
p.mpg()
```